# Excel Power Query causing scroll wheel issues

Tags: microsoft-excel, mouse, scrolling, power-query

I love Power Query, but I often have trouble with the the scroll wheel not working properly in workbooks that have query connections. Does anyone know of a fix for this that doesn't require VBA (i.e. saving as .xlsm)?

See [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/44558c03-411b-4c99-8160-96af233828e9/excell-2013-365-scroll-wheel-disabled-due-to-power-query) for further details and other people experiencing the same problem.

I'm using 64-bit Excel 2016, but this appears to be an issue in plenty of other versions as well.

Comment: Have you thought about "Focus"? There might not be an auto-focus set up in the software. You might have to click on the scroll bar first to access focus on the object. I've experience that in many a-software.

Comment: A work around is to double click in any cell and it works again. I don't think clicking the scroll bar helps.